# how to manage memory when using google map on html5 single page application

Tags: html, backbone.js, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

[image: MarkerWithLabel]

I dont know where else can i find best practise for implement google map on single page application. Currently I use backbonejs coupled with requirejs.

Upon page loaded for the first time, the number of marker created is only two. After hit the same route for the second time, the number of **MarkerWithLabel** object is double

Same goes to with other google map plugin (refer below).

[image: Overlapping Marker]

What else can I do to refresh/dispose/destroy those objects living in the JS memory?

**UPDATE:** Here is my code when i initiate the plugin:

1) I declare a global variable within the module

```
var $markers      = [],
    gm            = google.maps,
    iconWithColor = new google.maps.MarkerImage('./img/marker.svg', null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(25,25));
```

2) Code below is in another function within the module

```
var that = this;
require(["markerclusterer","markerwithlabel"], function () {
    _.each(coordinates.models, function(val, i) {
    var latLng = new gm.LatLng(val.get('in_latitude'), val.get('in_longitude')),
    marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: latLng,
        draggable: false,
        raiseOnDrag: true,
        map: that.map,
        labelContent: val.get('ig_label'),
        labelAnchor: new gm.Point(22, 0),
        labelClass: 'label',
        bgColour: colors,
        animation: gm.Animation.DROP,
        icon: iconWithColor,
        shadow: shadow
    });
    $markers.push(marker);
    gm.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        var new_marker = this;
        if(prev_marker) {
           if (prev_marker.getAnimation() != null) {                
           prev_marker.setAnimation(null);                              
           new_marker.setAnimation(gm.Animation.BOUNCE);
           prev_marker = new_marker;
           }
        } else {
           new_marker.setAnimation(gm.Animation.BOUNCE);
           prev_marker = new_marker;
        }
        that.map.panTo(latLng);
    }); 
    }, this);
});
```

3) I try to dispose by using

```
if($markers) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $markers.length; i++ ) {                    
    //console.log($markers[i]);
    $markers[i].setMap(null);
    delete $markers[i];
    }               
    $markers = [];
}   
if (markerCluster) {
    markerCluster.clearMarkers();
    markerCluster = null;
}
```

Comment: Apparently what you are facing are called Zombies in Backbone. Here is a great article to understand and avoid these http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

Comment: i already manage the view and the ui based on @derickbailey findings.

Comment: You have resource leaks, it's that simple.  Google Maps does not manage the markers and other features you add to the map canvas.  It's up to you to manage them.  If you share example code of how you use MarkerWithLabel and the marker spidifer, we can help find your leaks.

Comment: i already update my question. Pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($markers) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $markers.length; i++ ) {                    
      //console.log($markers[i]);
      google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners($markers[i]);
      $markers[i].setMap(null);
      delete $markers[i];
    }               
    $markers = [];
}
```

ok finally i successfully reduce number by destroying the listener only. Hope this help